# how to mount a folder from lxc

Tags: ubuntu, mount, lxc

I have the lxc, it has a running application. 
To edit the code of this application on own computer(Ubuntu 13.10), I want to mount a directory lxc. How can this be done?

for example

/var/lib/lxc/ubuntu_12_04/rootfs/home/

mounted in /mnt/lxc

Comment: This doesn't have much to do with `lxc`. The `rootfs` directory on the host OS is just a regular directory which you can safely write to from outside of the container, you can export it however you want (Samba, NFS, whatever)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to mount automatically a directory inside the lxc each time you start the lxc you can use the `lxc.mount.entry` directory inside `/var/lib/lxc/ubuntu_12_04/config` file. With Something like:

```
lxc.mount.entry = /mnt/lxc home/ none bind 0 0
```

This will mount `/mnt/lxc` inside the lxc root filesystem aka rootfs at `home/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

## Use "mount --bind"

### [man 8 mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount)

> -B, --bind
>
> ```
> Remount a subtree somewhere else (so that its contents are available in both places).
> ```

### Example

```bash
# make a mount point
sudo mkdir /mnt/lxc

# mount existing directory on the mount point
mount --bind /var/lib/lxc/ubuntu_12_04/rootfs/home/ /mnt/lxc
```

### Notes

1. Root has access to /var/lib/lxc/ubuntu_12_04/rootfs/home/ even without mounting.
2. The user id in the lxc instance should equal the user id in the host. Otherwise you may need to change users (`su someother_username`) or change file ownership (`chown myuser: somefile.txt`.) Ubuntu starts at the same user id by default so if you're using the default user in both places, the user ids should equal.
3. To check the user ids on files use `ls --numeric-uid-gid` or `ls -n`. Below you see a user id and group id of 1042.

   ```bash
   # show user and group ids
   ls -n
   -rw-r--r-- 1 1042 1042   0 May  15 15:31 example.txt
   ```