# How to start an lxc container on Ubuntu 14.04 without "Executing '/sbin/init' with no configuration file may crash the host" error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, lxc

**goal:** create a isolated linux system on Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS, 3.13.0-35-powerpc64-smp with an ultimate goal of running a hardened nginx server on this machine

After some research, I decided to try the recipe at http://www.unixmen.com/setting-multiple-isolated-linux-systems-containers-using-lxc-ubuntu-14-04/

I followed the instructions for installing lxc. I created a container with the following command:

```
lxc-create -n test-container -t ubuntu
```

However, when I tried to start the container

```
lxc-start -n test-container -d
```

I encountered an exception

> lxc_container: lxc_start.c: main: 296 Executing '/sbin/init' with no configuration file may crash the host

My research using google searches did not turn up any answers that I could understand so I installed the LXC web panel from http://lxc-webpanel.github.io/tools/install.sh to get an alternative perspective.

The LXC web panel shows my container in the general overview. If I try to start my container 'test-container' the container runs. It has no IP address.

Even though my container is running via the LXC web console, I do not know how to access it for use.

I would appreciate help in starting the container from the command line so that I may continue to follow the recipe at http://www.unixmen.com/setting-multiple-isolated-linux-systems-containers-using-lxc-ubuntu-14-04/

Any alternate methods for running a hardened and secure nginx server on this machine would also be appreciated.

Comment: have you tried `lxc-attach -n test-container` ?

Comment: I tried 'lxc-attach -n test-container'. The output is 'lxc-attach: attach.c: lxc_attach: 635 failed to get the init pid'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This comment [❝The user id in the lxc instance should equal the user id in the host.❞](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591678/how-to-mount-a-folder-from-lxc?rq=1) led me to my solution.

When I ran an IPython session as root, all functioned as expected. Duh!

`ps -aux | grep python`

> root      1327  0.0  0.4  18956 13188 ?        S    09:55   0:00
>   /usr/bin/python /srv/lwp/lwp.py

`sudo lxc-info --name test-container`

> Name:           test-container
>
> State:          STOPPED

`sudo lxc-attach -n test-container` functioned as expected.

Answer (score 3):

For me, It was a privileges problem, I just executed the lxc-start command with **sudo** and It worked.