# Why does lxc function as expected with lxc-webpanel and not from either CLI or python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, ubuntu, lxc

**observations**:

1. [lxc-webpanel](https://github.com/lxc-webpanel) functions as expected
2. lxc commands issued from command line interface and returns non-zero exit status 1
3. functions called from lxclite module within a python interpreter raise exceptions

**question**:

How can I locate the missing factor that allows lxc-webpanel to function as expected?  When I issue lxc commands in a bash shell or when I call the same defs that lxc-webpanel does from an python interpreter the lxc commands fail.

**goal**:

Be able to use the bash CLI or a python session to manage lxc containers

**system info**:

- No LSB modules are available.
- Distributor ID: Ubuntu
- Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
- Release:        14.04
- Codename:       trusty
- `uname -r`: 3.13.0-35-powerpc64-smp

A container named 'test-container' was created using the lxc-webpanel.

**observation 1: lxc-webpanel trial screenshots**

- [The container 'test-container' exists.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3067838/lxc_stackoverflow/container%20exists.png)
- [The container starts.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3067838/lxc_stackoverflow/can%20start%20container.png)
- [The container stops.](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3067838/lxc_stackoverflow/can%20stop%20container.png)

**observation 2: lxc commands from bash CLI**

- In: `lxc-info -qn test-container`

  Out:

> test-container doesn't exist

- In: `lxc-attach --name test-container`

  Out:

> attach.c: lxc_attach: 635 failed to get the init pid

**observation 3: lxclite def call from ipython3**

- In: 
  `import lxclite as lxc
  container = 'test-container'
  lxc.info(container)`

> ContainerDoesntExists                     Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 lxc.info(container)
>
> ../../python3_dev/_lxc/lxclite/**init**.py in info(container)
>       122     if not exists(container):
>       123         raise ContainerDoesntExists(
>   --> 124             'Container {} does not exist!'.format(container))
>       125
>       126     output = _run('lxc-info -qn {}|grep -i "State\|PID"'.format(container),
>
> ContainerDoesntExists: Container test-container does not exist!

NB: `lxc-checkconfig` output:

> Kernel configuration not found at /proc/config.gz; searching...
>
> Kernel configuration found at /boot/config-3.13.0-48-powerpc64-smp
>
> --- Namespaces ---
>
> Namespaces: [enabled]
>
> Utsname namespace: [enabled]
>
> Ipc namespace: [enabled]
>
> Pid namespace: [enabled]
>
> User namespace: [enabled]
>
> Network namespace: [enabled]
>
> Multiple /dev/pts instances: [enabled]
>
> --- Control groups ---
>
> Cgroup: [enabled]
>
> Cgroup clone_children flag: [enabled]
>
> Cgroup device: [enabled]
>
> Cgroup sched: [enabled]
>
> Cgroup cpu account: [enabled]
>
> Cgroup memory controller: [enabled]
>
> Cgroup cpuset: [enabled]
>
> --- Misc ---
>
> Veth pair device: [enabled]
>
> Macvlan: [enabled]
>
> Vlan: [enabled]
>
> File capabilities: [enabled]
>
> Note : Before booting a new kernel, you can check its configuration
>
> usage : CONFIG=/path/to/config /usr/bin/lxc-checkconfig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comment [❝The user id in the lxc instance should equal the user id in the host.❞](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22591678/how-to-mount-a-folder-from-lxc?rq=1) led me to my solution.

When I ran an IPython session as root, all functioned as expected. Duh!

`ps -aux | grep python`

> root      1327  0.0  0.4  18956 13188 ?        S    09:55   0:00
>   /usr/bin/python /srv/lwp/lwp.py

`sudo lxc-info --name test-container`

> Name:           test-container
>
> State:          STOPPED